# How to prevent web page from scrolling back to the top of the browser?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web page listing of items such as books, and it's been rendered by JavaScript, making requests to restful services. However, if I scroll down to the bottom of the browser, and select to view an item, and  then press the browser back button, the page doesn't scroll down to the bottom. Instead, it scrolls to the top of the browser.

How can I make it so that the web page scrolls back to the previous location?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are implementing the events.

I suppose you attached the event to a link and set the href attribute to "#". This is why the scroll goes back to the top.

If you are using jQuery, you can use the `preventDefault()` method from the Event object and it should work. Otherwise, if you return `false` in the event handler, the action should stop.

Can you provide some code of how you're calling the resful service?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your links use the anchor tag (#), even if the page doesnt reload. This way when user hits back they will be redirected to the last # and therefore the last position on the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp